# SqlException Error Message

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce, sqlconnection

I am developing an application that runs on windows Ce 6.0, the application should connect to a database that is located on my PC., but every time I try to open the connection i get A SQLException error message. this is how I am opening the connection

```
..........
SqlConnection EdiSqlConnection;
String ConnectionString;
ConnectionString = "Server='serverName';Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=true;";
..........

EdiSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

try {
    EdiSqlConnection.Open();
    Output.Text = "Connected"; //this is a message to see that we are connected
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Output.Text = "Message:   " + ex.Message;
    return;
}
```

Why am I getting the error message? and how do i resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: to start, remove the try catch and review the entire stacktrace provided by the exception. this will help determine what the problem is. If you need further assistance edit your post to include the entire stack trace.

Comment: What is the value of `ex.Message` in the `catch block?

Comment: the only output i am getting is :Message: SqlException

Comment: Is 'servername' and 'database' name the actual values in the string?  Or did you sanatize them for the sake of this post?  If those are actual values I would guess that your server is named something other than 'servername' and your db has a name other than 'databasename'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information here, so you'll need to provide more.

1. What type of exception is being thrown? Are you Sure its a `SqlException`? You are catching all exceptions.
2. What is the value of `ex.Message` in the `catch` block?
3. Which database are you connecting to? SQL Server (version?) or SQL Compact?

Assuming your application and the database are running on separate machines, you may have problems with trusted connection. Your WinCE device is unlikely to be on a domain or have a way to authenticate a user, so authentication will probably fail. Try using SSPI  authentication instead. See "Trusted Connection from a CE device" on [this page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008). Note that you don't have to give a domain user ID, just a user ID and password that is valid on the database server machine and which has access rights for the database.

Comment: apparently my code is correct, the problem was in the connection, My pc is running windows 7 and I guess security is very high on windows 7 and it is not allowing the windows ce unit to access it, so i have to figure out how to fix that now.

Comment: Try turning off your windows firewall. if that helps then turn it back on and add a rule for port 1433. Also check that sql server is listening on a tcpip port. It sent by default. I still think you'll have problems with trusted connection and you may have to use sql server authentication instead.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from `'serverName'`

Comment: i still get the same error! SqlException.... I think I should mention that I am trying to connect to my pc wirelessly...

Comment: Sorry It took me so long to get back at you, apparently my code is correct, the problem was in the connection, My pc is running windows 7 and I guess security is very high on windows 7 and it is not allowing the windows ce unit to access it, so i have to figure out how to fix that now.